# Is there way to send SMS from iPhone app without user prompt?

Tags: iphone, ios, sms

We are going to build iPhone app6 that sends SMS in background.

Can we send SMS without user probpting?

Comment: I seriously hope not, since sending an SMS usually costs money :)

Answer (score 4):

Short answer NO.

It is due to privacy concern, last time when I search for stuff similar to your task, I was not even able to pre-fill the number to send the text. i.e., like  pre-filling to email id when opening native mail app.

But you may explore private API to do this task.

Comment: Keeping in mind that using undocumented Cocoa Touch APIs usually results in Apple rejecting the app from the AppStore.

Comment: I'm pretty confident any app that sent SMS in the background would get rejected by Apple regardless of what API it used. *I seriously can't think of a single legitimate situation where this would be required.*

Comment: The only way we have found to do this (WITH PERMISSION) is using the Facebook Graph (FB Connect) interface to SMS people that the FaceBook user knows and has had to give us permission to do so.  BUT after that permission, everything is in the background.