# how to disable the default text sms confirm when send sms in Iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have written an app in iPhone. when I want to send sms text with encrypted string, the default sms confirm show all the string i send.

How can i disable this default sms confirm by code?

is it possible to do this?

any suggestion?

thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to hide the confirm teh alertviwe completely?If yes you can not.It is only possible in Anrdoid sending messages with out confirmation

Comment: yes i don't want any thing show up after i press my button in my app, this is about security problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case as also discussed in these threads

[Is there way to send SMS from iPhone app without user prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609865/is-there-way-to-send-sms-from-iphone-app-without-user-prompt)

[How to send In-App SMS in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280830/how-to-send-in-app-sms-in-iphone)

due to privacy policy of apple you can not get rid of the user prompt for sending message.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i am really new with sending sms. thanks anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately IOS is not that flexible like Android but it also has its own drawbacks and advantages.

Answer (score 0):

It's by design; You could spam premium rate numbers if the user did not know you were sending SMS.